# Accessing files from remote/network locations in R

Tags: mysql, r, networking, filepath

### Background

I'm in the midst of putting together a framework involving R and MySQL that can handle actual data being scattered across several machines/computers. AFAIU, it's a good idea to only dump the (permanent) Fully Qualified Names (FQN) of the different files in the DB instead of putting the actual objects there (images, documents, R-objects etc.)

Now, I'd like this framework to be as flexible/generic as possible, so it needs to be able handle the following aspects:

- different OS directory structures, mainly Windows and Linux
- different machines in totally different locations -> different IPs or DNS-names, subnets etc.
- every data file, wherever it may reside, needs to be accessible via R on a master machine in order to load and analyze the data contained in that file

Unfortunately, my entire background on network related aspects is totally auto-didactic and I'm feeling I'm lacking some basic knowledge here.

So these are my actual questions:

### Questions

1. What are the file path components that are relevant if I want to store paths to arbitrary drives and directories on a computer?

   Something like ***hostname:port(?)/driveletter/directory/subdirectory/filename.fileextension***?

   or is this only possible if host runs a webserver such as Apache that allows me to access a certain directory only?
2. What components does R expect in order to being able to **directly** load a given file from a remote network location?

   Running Windows XP, I always mapped the target drive to a network drive, then R has no trouble with ***networkdrive/dir/subdir/filename.filext***. But I'm interested in the raw details of doing that without network drives.

### Follow Up 2012-01-27

Using URLs and considering security aspects as suggested by Vincent, I could then use all components that can make up a valid URL, right? But probably only, if there's a true webserver that can handle user credentials.

```
scheme-specific-part
     |
http://hans:geheim@example.org:80/demo/example.cgi?land=de&city=aa#history
|      |    |      |           | |                 |                |
|      |    |      host        | url-path          searchpart       fragment
|      |    password           port
|      user
scheme
```

### Update 2012-02-01

I have to say I'm still kind of lost with network stuff. I managed to read a *local* file like this

```
path <- url("file:///C:/temp/test.html")
readLines(path)
```

So far, so good. But how do I connect to another host in the network? Following the URL structure from above, I tried something like

```
path <- url("http://user:password@141.78.x.x/desiredDirectory")
path <- url("http://user:password@141.78.x.x:80/desiredDirectory")
```

but failed to end up with a valid (open) connection object. The host is a NAS-drive which requires authentification when accessing its IP. Any idea how I can connect to it from R?

Maybe, this is possible with some RCurl function?

Comment: You can use URLs: R can read files from URLs, transparently, as if they were local files. You can use http, as you suggest, or ftp (http is probably easier and safer).
Allowing access to arbitrary directories looks like a security issue, especially if the machines are in totally different locations...

Comment: Thanks man. Sure, mentally I'm still in a pure development mode, but of course security measures need to be considered as well.

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution to your problem? Would be nice to know :)

Comment: Not really for this particular problem. But for another project I did use `character` based connection strings for a `HTTPS` connection (containing username and passwort) and that worked just fine!